# Strange "DuckDuckGo dork" takes me to random website

Tags: duckduckgo

I don't know if this is the correct place to share this, but here goes:

If I search this phrase:

`\t _  _\n\t|_||_|\n\t _   _\n\t| |_| |\n\t\\_____/`

with DuckDuckGo, it takes me to `https://login.i-ready.com/`. The phrase is a compressed ascii-art of a smiley face.

Any ideas what on earth causes this strange thing to happen?

I don't even really know if this is suitable for stack exchange, I'm just curious why this happens.

EDIT: It really is random, not just a single website.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a "*feature*" called "*!Bang*"... as documented here: [here](https://duckduckgo.com/bang_lite.html) and [here](https://duckduckgo.com/bang). There is nothing special about this string (try cutting it down), aside from the very first `\`.

Specifically giving a `!` or `\` at the beginning of your query will have a special effect... `!` goes to a registered site for quick access, while `\` goes to the first search result.

A couple of examples they give are:

- `!youtube` or `!yt`
- `!g`

If you type your "*query*" character by character, then you'll see the autocomplete options appear below.

Fundamentally, entering `\stackexchange` in the search box is equivalent to searching for `stackexchange` and then immediately clicking the top link.

Equally, entering `\t _  _\n\t|_||_|\n\t _   _\n\t| |_| |\n\t\\_____/` will take you to the first result of the query `t _  _\n\t|_||_|\n\t _   _\n\t| |_| |\n\t\\_____/`.

[image: example autocomplete for \]

[image: example autocomplete for !]

Comment: This explains the idea behind *!bangs* but doesn't explain *why OPs search query works*. As far as I can see, `\t` isn't bound to any sort of !bang. For obvious reasons, I'm a bit reluctant to try this out for myself.

Comment: @grooveplex `\t` makes you go to the first search result of query `t`. If you search for the query from the question but without leading `\ `, then you see that i-ready is the first result.  It doesn't have to be bound like the bang. Actually I think `\ `  isn't really part of the bang feature but its own feature.

Comment: @kapex Woah, that's so cool! I had no idea. Thanks for enlightening me :)